# Is there a working example of yaml-cpp for Visual Studio?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I've been looking for more than just documentation ( example code and YAML file ) to be able to get going quickly with Yaml-Cpp.  I'd prefer a Visual Studio ( 2019 ) solution if someone can point me to it.

Answer (score 3):

One solution if you are using `cmake`, you can use [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

installing it as documented and then `vcpkg install yaml-cpp`.

after in your `CMakeLists.txt` you can add:

```cpp
find_package(yaml-cpp CONFIG REQUIRED)
### your other config here ...
### ...
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE yaml-cpp) #main is your executable target's name
```

after that in your "main.cpp" it would be enough something like:

```cpp
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#pragma warning(disable: 4251)
#pragma warning(disable: 4275)
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#pragma warning(pop)

#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem> // this is C++17, just foe eg to save a YAML file.

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {

  fs::path pf = "file.yaml"; // you can use std::string as well
  std::ofstream wf(pf, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
  if (!wf.is_open()) {
    return 1;
   }

    int values[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    YAML::Emitter out(wf);
    out << YAML::BeginMap;
    out << YAML::Key << "MyKey" << YAML::Value << YAML::BeginSeq;
    for (auto& v : values) {
            out << v;
    }
    out << YAML::EndSeq << YAML::EndMap;

    wf.close();
    if (!wf.good()) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: the `#pragma warning(...)` are for disabling some warning related, so optional.

This should be enough to have a "quicksart" as an example.

Comment: That is especially wonderful in GitHub Actions! Thanks!